# Bootstrap 3.0 width: Why is the pixel width of entire page wider than other pages?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm implementing Bootstrap on a current site to make it responsive.

Right now the current site is fixed width at 960px.

If I look at a Bootstrap example with a fixed width of 960px, the content area is much narrower than the content area of our current site. It looks like about 200px narrower. Yet, if I look at the Chrome Inspector, the container width is confirmed to be 960px on both sites.

If I hover over the `<html>` tag in Chrome Inspector on the Bootstrap tab, the width of the viewport shows 1684px. If I do the same on the current site, or any other website in the same Chrome browser, the width of the viewport is 1263px.

This would explain why the content area of the Bootstrap example appears narrower, but my question is why? I'm guessing it's a very simple answer, but I haven't been able to find one...

Comment: So you're saying the values are showing the same, but visually it looks totally different? Do you have links to both examples for others to see? The only thing I can think of, is that there must be other CSS in your website that's changing the view. Maybe you're using different padding values for the container class?

Comment: You probably didn't wrap your page in a  `.container`. If you did and still get this behaviour, your `.container` has a `.row-fluid` ancestor which needs to be changed to `.row`.

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: @Lee, that's correct, that the width values are the same, 960px for the current non-bootstrap [link](http://www.interactivestem.org) and the bootstrap example. The bootstrap content takes up less width visually on the screen. If you go to the bootstrap page such as [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), go to Inspector, and hover over <html> you'll see the title popup in the upper-left that the viewport width will be wider than any other site not using bootstrap (at least that's what I've found).

Comment: Okay, I'm finding it hard to follow this. The Interactive Stem link you gave, is not bootstrap, and has no CSS rules to show it is. The container class has a set width of 960px. You want to remove that style rule, because it If anything, your site is narrower than the BS site. I don't think your question is very clear to be honest. The Bootstrap framework sets the container width at 1170px, 970px, 750px, and 100% going from largest to smallest width. Can you show us visually what's wrong, and what you want it to look like?

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear. The current site does not yet have Bootstrap applied. I'm about to work on converting. Which is why I'm confused when I compare a Bootstrap site with mine. The current non-Bootstrap site is fixed width 960px. When I look at any Bootstrap example and change the width in Inspector to 960px and remove all padding, the Bootstrap fixed container is visually much narrower than my non-Bootstrap site. This is why I referenced hovering over <html> in the Inspector. In Bootstrap the pixel width of the entire viewport is wider.

Comment: I don't see it. The `html` elements on your site and the bootstrap site you link to have the same widths; when I go full screen, both `html`s are 1905 px wide. Are you sure you're not zoomed, on one of the sites?

Comment: Try ctrl/cmd-0 to make sure you are not zoomed in.